# Block normalization of histogram of oriented gradient

Tags: python, c++, image-processing

I am a beginner in image processing. I have some questions regarding HOG.

https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/

From this website, it mentioned that each element inside the HOG descriptor will be divided by the sum of all elements in a block. However, how to do block normalization if overlapping the blocks? I do not understand because some elements in the vector will be elements of more than one blocks.

[Picture of block normalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wcAc.png)

For example, if we have a histogram [v11 v12 v13 v14...v19] ,[v21 v22 v23 v24...v29], [v31 v32 v33 v34 v35...v39] and [v41 v42 v43 v44..v49] in the red block, we can normalize the first element of the first vector like this: v11/(v11+v12+...+v21+v22+v23+..+v31+v32+...+v41+v42...+v49)

However, how can I normalize the vectors in the red block and yellow block?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what's the problem? maybe, are you trying to normalize each block *in-place* and realized that this won't work with overlapping blocks ? just store the result in a *different* vector per block ... otherwise, can you better explain what you didn't understand ?

Comment: Yep, you normalize copies of the blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited my question. I hope it can help.

Comment: for each 8x8 pixel block you have a 9x1 vector; by stepping 8 pixels at a time horizontally (and then vertically), you have for each 16x16 block four 9x1 = one 36x1 vector; **this** vector = [v1,..,v36] should be normalized according to L2 norm, that is [v1/sqrt(v1^2+v2^2+...+v36^2),...]

Comment: How about overlapping the blocks? How to normalize them if we overlap the blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Expansion on @Massimiliano Janes' comment:

Suppose your histograms were

```
h1 = [v11, v12, v13, ..., v19],

h2 = [v21, v22, v23, ..., v29], 

h3 = [v31, v32, v33, ..., v39],

h4 = [v41, v42, v43, ..., v49] for the red block.
```

So to normalize the red block, you would divide by the sum of all elements h1, h2, h3 and h4.

```
sum = v11 + v12 + ... + v19 + v21 + ... + v49
```

Now, new normalized histograms would be

```
h1_new = [v11/sum, v12/sum, ..., v19/sum]

h2_new = [v21/sum, v22/sum, ..., v29/sum]

h3_new = [v31/sum, v32/sum, ..., v39/sum]

h4_new = [v41/sum, v42/sum, ..., v49/sum]
```

But for normalizing the yellow block, you would still use the original histograms of the two cells of the red block, that is, h2 and h4.

Comment: What's unclear here, is that after normalising the red and yellow blocks, you will have `h2_new_red` and `h2_new_yellow`; in fact, for every histogram apart from the ones around the edge, you will have 4 normalised versions. How to merge these?